# Does Fourier Transform only process periodic signal?

Tags: image-processing, signals, signal-processing, dft, continuous-fourier

The aperiodic signal could be processed by DFT. DFT can process both periodic and aperiodic signal?

Comment: From Some Tutorial:  DTFT can process discrete aperiodic signal, DFT can process discrete periodic signal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Discrete Fourier Transform (DFT) defines a relationship between an N-point time-domain sequence x[n], n=0..N-1, and an N-point frequency domain sequence (samples of the Fourier transform uniformly spaced between \omega = 0 and 2\pi) X[k], k=0..N-1.  The forward transformation is given by:

```
X[k] = 1/N \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} x[n] exp{-j 2\pi k.n/N}
```

which can be expressed as a matrix multiply

```
X = D x
```

where x and X are N-element column vectors corresponding to the time and frequency domains, and D is the N-by-N DFT matrix,

```
D_{kn} = 1/N exp{-j 2\pi k.n/N}
```

(and thus the inverse transform is trivially derived from the matrix inverse of D).

As such, you can calculate X[k] for any N-point input sequence x[n], and it doesn't even make that much sense to define periodicity for a finite-length sequence.  If x[n] can be broken into several pieces that exactly repeat (e.g., a repeated N/2 point sequence), then we will see corresponding structure in X[k] (all the odd-numbered spectral samples will be zero for this example).

Now, you can interpret the DFT as the Fourier transform of an infinite-duration, periodic sequence consisting of infinitely many repeats of the N-point time-domain sequence you start with.  In this case, the DFT values X[k] correspond to the weights of the Dirac deltas that constitute the spectrum of this infinite-energy (but finite-power) sequence.

But you can also interpret it as sampling the Fourier transform of finite-length sequence, equivalently an infinite-duration sequence that happens to be nonzero only over a finite, N-point range.  In this case, the X[k] values are the finite-valued samples of the the full, continuous-frequency Fourier transform.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. A good explanation is [made here](http://www.swarthmore.edu/NatSci/echeeve1/Class/e12/Lectures/FourierXform/FourierXFormI.html) 
Directly quoted below. ( http://www.swarthmore.edu/NatSci/echeeve1/Class/e12/Lectures/FourierXform/FourierXFormI.html )

> It seems that a periodic function would not have a Fourier Transform
>   because it violates the first of the convergence criteria.  However,
>   if we allow for impulse functions, we can get around this restriction
>   (this will allow us to use Fourier Transforms for both periodic and
>   aperiodic functions).
>
> Consider the a frequency domain function that is a simple impulse
>   scaled by 2p (the scaling factor will be convenient a bit later).

[image]

> We can find the corresponding time domain function by calculating the
>   inverse Fourier Transform,

[image]

> (The last step was performed using the sifting property of the impulse
>   function.)  Note that the time domain function, x(t), is periodic.  So
>   if we allow impulses in the Fourier domain we can have periodic
>   functions in the time domain.  This was a special case, but we can
>   represent any (subject to convergence criteria like those for the
>   Fourier Series) periodic function with a Fourier Transform.  First
>   consider a Fourier Transform that is an infinite sum of impulses (this
>   is contrived, but it simplifies to something useful).

[image]

> (This derivation also uses the sifting property.)  So, to find the
>   Fourier Transform of a periodic signal, x(t), first find the Fourier
>   Series coefficients, cn, then

[image]

Comment: Your answer only covers periodic signals, and misses the point that the DFT can be used on periodic extension of aperiodic signals.